# how can i validate a date using carbon on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to validate a date that should be after todays date like tomorrow or 1 day/month/year. bu i cant get it. So far i try this

```
$date=Carbon::now()->today()->calendar();
        $this->validate($request, [
            'submission_date'=>'required|after:$date'
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel provides `after:date` and `after_or_equal:date` [See docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-after)

```php
'submission_date' => 'required|date|after:tomorrow'
// or
'submission_date' => 'required|date|after_or_equal:tomorrow'

// or
'submission_date' => 'date|after:"2019-09-30 10:48:11"',
```

Answer (score 0):

Carbon have built-in method [`isFuture`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/version-1.29/src/Carbon/Carbon.php#L2307) to validate a future date :

```php
$request->submission_date->isFuture()
```

Comment: $project->submission_date=$request->submission_date->isFuture(); Itried this and i got this  errorCall to a member function isFuture() on string

Comment: @TanvirAhmed parse it first. Carbon::parse($request->submission_date)->isFuture()

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Just change some things.

```
$date=Carbon::now()->today();
$this->validate($request, [
    'submission_date'=>"required|after:$date"
]);
```

> look the change  " " instead of ' '